# How do I install **Pytorch** with conda? Is anaconda.org down temporarily?

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, conda

I just installed Anaconda and now I'm trying to install **pytorch** via `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`. But I'm getting the error message

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE: BACK-END SERVER IS AT CAPACITY for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:00.635763
CF-RAY: 5c7c36945d34c4a4-DUS

A remote server error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.

A 500-type error (e.g. 500, 501, 502, 503, etc.) indicates the server failed to
fulfill a valid request.  The problem may be spurious, and will resolve itself if you
try your request again.  If the problem persists, consider notifying the maintainer
of the remote server.
```

How can I resolve this and install pytorch? Is anaconda.org just down temporarily?

Comment: Which OS you are using. Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is in your question itself . The last paragraph says that :

```
A 500-type error (e.g. 500, 501, 502, 503, etc.) indicates the server failed to
fulfill a valid request.  The problem may be spurious, and will resolve itself if you
try your request again.  If the problem persists, consider notifying the maintainer
of the remote server.
```

This would mean that you would have to try again later . This generally happens when the official websites are down and this has happened earlier as well . So you just have to wait it out.

Comment: In December 2020, the server was working at some point. Now, in January 2021, I get this error again.
There is an associated GitHub issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/51029